# Null Pointer exception with Private method

Tags: apex, trigger

I have code below which is throwing

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

when COMPLETED_CASE_STATUS string variable is assigned.  Is it because its private method and cannot access public variable ?

```
public with sharing class TriggerHandler extends TriggerHandlerAbstract {
    public static final String COMPLETED_CASE_STATUS = 'Completed';

    private static void updateCasesRelated(List<BackEnd_Result__c> newValues) {
        for (BackEnd_Result__c item : newValues) {
            Case tempCase = item.SF_CaseID__c != null ? casesById.get(item.SF_CaseID__c) : casesById.get(item.SF_ApplicationID__c);
            if (item.Result__c != BACK_END_RESULT_COMPLETED
                && (intSettings.Integration_Enabled__c && intSettings.Base_registration_enabled__c && intSettings.Settlement_system_registration_enabled__c)) {
                tempCase.Status = NEW_CASE_STATUS;
                tempCase.BackEndResult__c = item.Id;
            } else {
                if (!(intSettings.Integration_Enabled__c && intSettings.Base_registration_enabled__c && intSettings.Settlement_system_registration_enabled__c)) {
                    tempCase.Status = Consts.Case1.Status.Done.getDevName();
                } else {
                    tempCase.Status = COMPLETED_CASE_STATUS;
                }
            }
            toUpdate.add(tempCase);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is `tempCase` ? The reason you are getting that error is because `tempCase` might be `null`. Can you please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/273605/null-pointer-exception-with-private-method) the question to include the relevant code.

Comment: I feel may be the `tempcase` is not instantiated. I have added the relevent code.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because of the below line

```
Case tempCase = item.SF_CaseID__c != null ? casesById.get(item.SF_CaseID__c) : casesById.get(item.SF_ApplicationID__c);
```

In the above line if `casesById` map doesn't have a matching key, it will return `null` and hence your `tempCase` will be `null`. And if you try to access the attributes of the `null` variable, you are bound to get the error which you are getting. And you are getting error at this line `tempCase.Status = COMPLETED_CASE_STATUS;` because it does not satisfy any other conditions and in `else` condition, it tries to set the value of `null` object.

One of the way by which you can avoid this error is by having a `null` check for `tempCase` before setting the value of its attributes.

```
Case tempCase = item.SF_CaseID__c != null ? casesById.get(item.SF_CaseID__c) : casesById.get(item.SF_ApplicationID__c);
if(tempCase!=null){
    if (item.Result__c != BACK_END_RESULT_COMPLETED
            && (intSettings.Integration_Enabled__c && intSettings.Base_registration_enabled__c && intSettings.Settlement_system_registration_enabled__c)) {
        tempCase.Status = NEW_CASE_STATUS;
        tempCase.BackEndResult__c = item.Id;
    } else {
        if (!(intSettings.Integration_Enabled__c && intSettings.Base_registration_enabled__c && intSettings.Settlement_system_registration_enabled__c)) {
            tempCase.Status = Consts.Case1.Status.Done.getDevName();
        } else {
            tempCase.Status = COMPLETED_CASE_STATUS;
        }
    }
    toUpdate.add(tempCase);
}
```

**Note :** Ideally you should have a `containsKey` check in the `map` and `get` the `value` from `map` only if the `key` is present in the `map`

Comment: Ah, I now get the OP's comment about "when COMPLETED_CASE_STATUS is assigned" .

Comment: Hi @SFKumar if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.